# How do i call insert from main?

Tags: c++

with the given code, How do i call insert from main?
I tried, but I always got error :expected primary-expression before.
what is the primary-expression exactly?

```
    Object & front( )
      { return *begin( ); }

    const Object & front( ) const
      { return *begin( ); }

    Object & back( )
      { return *--end( ); }

    const Object & back( ) const
      { return *--end( ); }

    void push_front( const Object & x )
      { insert( begin( ), x ); }

    void push_back( const Object & x )
      { insert( end( ), x ); }

    void pop_front( )
      { erase( begin( ) ); }

    void pop_back( )
      { erase( --end( ) ); }

    // Insert x before itr.
    iterator insert( iterator itr, const Object & x )
    {
        Node *p = itr.current;
        theSize++;
        return iterator( p->prev = p->prev->next = new Node( x, p->prev, p ) );
    }
```

Comment: The code you have above won't compile by itself, and it doesn't include `main`.  Can you share a complete example including the `Object`, `Node`, declarations and `main`.

Comment: In your code example there is not enough context to answer. For help you will have to give us a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

To call a function from main:

```
void My_Function()
{
  std::cout << "My_Function\n"
}

int main()
{
  My_Function();
  return 0;
}
```

To call an object's method from main:

```
class Object
{
  public:
    void print() { std::cout << "Object\n";}
};

int main()
{
  Object o;
  o.print();
  return 0;
}
```

You should be able to find these examples in some good C++ textbooks.

**Edit 1:  Static Object functions**

You could also declare a method as `static` inside an object:

```
class Object_With_Static
{
  public:
    static void Print_Name()
    {
       std::cout << "Object_With_Static\n";
    };
};

int main()
{
  Object_With_Static::Print_Name();
  return 0;
}
```